# Unable to render images in caraousel from database in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to render images from my database to carousel in Django. I have a model which contains url fields to store images url but when I use them in (template.html) my carousel img src, it only renders 1st image but not others even though I have three images url stored in database. To understand it better here is my code.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class CaraouselData(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
    image = models.URLField(null = False, default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    caraousel_data = CaraouselData.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', context={
        'caraousel_data': caraousel_data,
    })
```

**template.js**

```
{% block content %}

{#    Caraousel Data Section#}
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        </div>
          {# images fetching from models #}
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            {% for item in caraousel_data %}
          <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %} active" {% endif %}>
            <img src="{{ item.image }}" width="600" height="670" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>{{ item.title }}</h5>
              <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not installed the pillow library.
To handle images you must install them first.